# how do I run code when a user logs into linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, startup, chmod

I need to figure out a way to have some lines of code run when a user logs in.
The lines of code I want to run are

```
cd DroneSoftware/
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
node app.js
```

I have tried following this guide https://medium.com/@elhardoum/automatically-start-node-js-server-on-system-restarts-cab3d2194674 but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

Maybe I am doing something wrong in my crontab

```
sh -c 'cd /path/to/my/app && sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0 && node app.js'
```

I am completely new to linux so any help would be appreciated!
please let me know if more information is needed.

edit: If I understand Blancos link correctly crontab runs before the network manager.  while node js creates a port so does anyone have a way to accomplish this without using crontab or at least a way around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could just try using a bash script to execute this.
Create a new startup script similar to the following,

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd /path/to/DroneSoftware/
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
node app.js
```

Follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up to create a new startup script.

Comment: Note that you will need to make sure you have passwordless sudo access or else the script is going to wait for a password to be typed

Comment: thank you I just added passwordless sudo access.  For future readers I used the following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYLwTkVoGuY

Comment: @Blanco thank you for the suggestion. Most of those are suggesting crontab but I worry that cron runs too early for a node app to run properly.  any idea if that is an issue?